# How do I solve the error Ambiguous column name with join

Tags: sql, join

I'm currently struggling with a join where the column [NAME] results in an error (ambiguous column). I'm pretty new at SQL and someone else made the first join for me, so I now just tried to replicate this with something else I wanted to join and as I understood, I do need to add the columnname of the data I'm trying to join to the table, otherwise it won't show that datacolumn. I renamed the table to INVENTGROUP, but still I get this error. What am I doing wrong? Many thanks for your help! Below you can find my complete query.

```
SELECT [SALESID]
,[INVOICEID]
,[INVOICEDATE]
,[LINENUM]
,[PRICEUNIT]
,[DISCPERCENT]
,[LINEAMOUNT]
,[TRANSACTIONCODE]
,[DELIVERYTYPE]
,[LINEPERCENT]
,[DLVDATE]
,[INVENTQTY]
,[INVENTREFTYPE]
,[REMAINBEFORE]
,[QBE_COSTPRICE]
,[QBE_ITEMTXT]
,[MODIFIEDDATETIME]
,[CREATEDDATETIME]
,[ISSM_WARRANTYPACKNAME]
,[QBE_LINEAMOUNTMSTPURCHEXCHDATE]
,[DATAAREAID]
,[ITEMID]
,[QTY]
,[CURRENCYCODE]
,[SALESPRICE]
,[Brand]
,[CostCenter]
,[Department] 
,[NAME]
,INVOICE.[RECID]
,INVOICE.[ITEMGROUPID]
FROM [ELG_DynamicsAX_DWH].[dbo].[CUSTINVOICETRANS] AS INVOICE
JOIN(SELECT[Brand]
,[CostCenter]
,[Department]
,[RECID]
From [ELG_DynamicsAX_DWH].[dbo].[CustInvoiceTransFinDim]) AS FINDIM ON FINDIM.RECID = INVOICE.RECID
JOIN(SELECT[NAME]
,[ITEMGROUPID]
From [ELG_DynamicsAX_DWH].[dbo].[INVENTITEMGROUP]) AS INVENTGROUP ON INVENTGROUP.ITEMGROUPID = INVOICE.ITEMGROUPID
```

Comment: It's good programming practice to qualify all columns, at least when several tables are involved. E.g. `FINDIM.RECID` instead of just `RECID`.

Comment: Use meaningful table aliases throughout.

Comment: You're getting the error because you have a `Brand` column in your `INVOICE` table and another one in your `FINDIM` table (the first join).

If you're dealing with joins, it is useful to alias the tables (`INVOICE` is an alias) and then use the qualified name, i.e I`NVOICE.Brand` (or `FINDIM.Brand` if that's what you want)

I would personally use shorter aliases on the tables so that it's easier to reference them.

Also, you don't have to wrap every column name in brackets, that is just necessary if your column name conflicts with a keyword or has spaces or other 'unusual' characters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you please check if this table "CUSTINVOICETRANS" also has a column "Name", same column is also present in table "ELG_DynamicsAX_DWH". make sure in select you use alias where ever column name is conflicting with 2 tables/ correlated subquery.

Comment: Thank you Nishant, you are completey right, stupid of me, there is in fact a column in the CUSTINVOICETRANS that has the same name [NAME] . I totally overlooked that because I didn't include it. I've now added an alias to the column I need to add and now it works. Again thank you, I've been staring at my screen for the past hour.